# How to understand probability of random vector uniformly distributed in each component

Tags: probability

Let $\boldsymbol{x}$ be a random vector such that $\boldsymbol{x}\in [a,b]^n$. Assume each $x_{i} \sim \text{Uniform} (a,b)$ and assume the components of $\boldsymbol{x}$ are independent. Then

$$P(\boldsymbol{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{b-a} = \frac{n}{b-a}$$

which means for $ n > b-a$, then $P(\boldsymbol{x}) > 1$.

How is this possible? I thought a probability density function was a mapping $P:\Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$, but in this case, the probability wouldn't fit in $[0,1]$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that a probability *density* (as opposed to *distribution*) function $f$ of a (real) random variable *can* excede $1$ anyway. We need that $P(X\in[u,v])\le 1$, i.e., $\int_u^vf(t)\,\mathrm dt\le 1$, which still allows $f(t)>1$. Just think of a uniform distribution over a tiny interval!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(\boldsymbol{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{b-a} =\left[ \frac{1}{b-a}\right]^n$$

It's a product, not a sum

Comment: lol been studying too hard. need sleep. thanks very much.

Comment: If $[a,b]=\{a,a+1,\ldots, b\}$, then all the $b-a$ should be $b+1-a$.